# How to define NDepend API CQLinq execution context in c#?

Tags: api, ndepend, cqlinq

When I port a NDepend CQLinq query to C# I must allways start defining a codeBase to query to, so this CQLinq query

```
from m in Methods
where m.ILCyclomaticComplexity > 10 
select new {m}
```

using NDepend API in C# I must port to:

```
ICodeBase codeBase

from m in codeBase.Application.Methods
where m.ILCyclomaticComplexity > 10 
select m
```

I see there is a ICQLinqExecutionContext. Can I define the context for the queries so I can directly use Assemblies, Methods, JustMyCode, ...etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explaine in the [ICQLinqExecutionContext](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Reserved.CQLinq.ICQLinqExecutionContext.html) doc: *This interface is reserved for CQLinq implementation usage and is not intended to be used in your code.*

But as you noticed, with just a little bit of rewritten, you can access 100% of CQLinq features (like using `codeBase.Application.Methods` intead of just `Methods`)

Also by reading the [CQLinq syntax doc about predefined domain](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx#PredefinedDomains), you can see that a domain like `Methods` in CQLinq gets translated to `context.CodeBase.Methods` at CQLinq post-compilation time. What you are really missing is not the interface `ICQLinqExecutionContext` but CQLinq post-compilation time that is not available in C#.